# How does Thor know that the invasion in Avengers will be in New York?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012

In *Avengers* we see many of the Avengers find/work out where Loki's portal machine is being set up:

> Banner sees the radiation mapper pay off before he Hulks out. Stark and Captain America work it out and tell Hawkeye and Black Widow. Fury follows the Quinjet.

But we don't see Thor find out from anyone else, is it ever revealed how he knows to head for New York after he gets out of the falling cage?

Comment: other than New York being where headquarters is and that is a good place to start when needing to reconnect with your team?

Comment: @NKCampbell But Stark Tower doesn't become the Avengers head quarters until after they win the battle of New York.

Comment: Thor drops off the helicarrier about the same time as Banner. Banner is within driving distance of New York, and Thor arrives after the portal opens. So probably Thor just looked up, saw the portal, and headed for it.

Comment: Banner could have told them "New York" but where *specifically* is something Stark had to figure out.

Comment: Thor also knew where to look for when Loki was first captured and being transported by the quinjet. So they either have some sort of brotherly connection or Thor is very good at finding his brother (or he looked up into the air as pointed out by @DaaaahWhoosh)

Answer (score 6):

There could be multiple possibilities

**1. Thor had help from Asgard**

Thor was sent to earth to stop Loki and bring him back to Asgard. At his first scene in the movie, he exactly lands on a moving airplane where Loki is. Odin transported him to Loki's location.

After he fell off from the helicarrier, Heimdal or Odin could have told him the location of Loki.

**2. He was nearby and saw the portal**

As [DaaaahWhoosh](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/46611/daaaahwhoosh) pointed out in his comments,

> Thor drops off the helicarrier about the same time as Banner. Banner
>   is within driving distance of New York, and Thor arrives after the
>   portal opens. So probably Thor just looked up, saw the portal, and
>   headed for it.

**3. SHIELD contacted Thor**

As soon as Fury saw the helicarrier leaving he knowns that Avengers have found Loki and follows them. He also orders Maria Hill to restore communications at once. He could have contacted Thor. With flights and numerous men at his disposal it would have easy for him to locate where Thor crash landed.

The helicarrier's communication went down in the attack. But since Fury was able to contact Stark, council during the battle I assume the communications were back online soon.

Comment: First one looks most plausible. *Thor: Ragnarok* shows that Heimdall can help Thor in such situations.

Comment: 4. Thor watches Earth movies on his spare time and has thus learned that aliens always attack New York